# Checking equality of elements in 2 dataframes in R column by column

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, equality

I'm trying to check the equality of the elements of two dataframes in R column by column using the `all.equal` function, and I want to do this using a for loop. I'm new to R so I'm not sure how to write a for loop including two dataframes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this question hasn't been answered so I figured I'd put down an answer for future reference.

To provide a working example I'll be using the `mtcars` dataset that comes with R as part of the `datasets` package.

So to start off, let's create a dummy dataset to compare with mtcars. Let's call this dataset `mtcars2` and let's make columns 5 and 11, `drat` and `carb` respectively, differ to some extent from their original `mtcars` counterparts, while keeping columns 1 to 4 and columns 6 to 10 intact. To "mess" up columns 5 and 11, we'll use `jitter()` in combination with simple multiplication.

```
mtcars2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(mtcars[, 1:4], "drat" = jitter(mtcars[,5]) * 4,
                               mtcars[,6:10], "carb" = jitter(mtcars[,11])* 0.5))
```

So now we have a dummy dataset to compare to `mtcars` in our for-loop. Next we prepare a data.frame to write in the results of our for-loop. We'll need a data.frame that has a number of rows equal to the number of columns we're going to compare, and we need two columns, one `col_number` to show which column the corresponding `all.equal()` result refers to. And then, of course, we need another column, `AE_result` to store the result of the `all_equal()` function we'll be calling. We'll call this data.frame `df_AE` and we'll declare `col_number` to be a numeric vector, and `AE_result` to be a character vector.

```
width <- ncol(mtcars)
df_AE <- as.data.frame(matrix(0L, nrow = width, ncol = 2))

names(df_AE) <- c("col_number", "AE_result")
class(df_AE$col_number) <- "numeric"
class(df_AE$AE_result) <- "character"
```

So now we're ready for **the actual for-loop**, where we'll count our way through the columns, calling `all.equal` on each pair of columns, and writing the counter (`i`) and the result (`x`) to our `df_AE` data.frame.

```
for (i in 1:width) {
    x <- all.equal(mtcars[, i], mtcars2[, i])
    df_AE[i,1] <- i
    df_AE[i,2] <- x
}
```

So now when we call `df_AE` we'll get something like this:

```
df_AE

> df_AE
       col_number                           AE_result
1           1                                TRUE
2           2                                TRUE
3           3                                TRUE
4           4                                TRUE
5           5  Mean relative difference: 3.000102
6           6                                TRUE
7           7                                TRUE
8           8                                TRUE
9           9                                TRUE
10         10                                TRUE
11         11 Mean relative difference: 0.4982218
```